# java Generics Wildcard

Tags: java, generics, type-systems

I have a question on the use of wildcards in Java's generic types: what is the basic difference between `List<? extends Set>` and `List<T extends Set>`? When would I use either?

Comment: A better question is what is the difference between either of those and `List`...

Comment: @Blindy: That's a completely different question.

Comment: simple. `List<T extends Set>` is not valid syntax

Answer (score 9):

Two reasons:

**To avoid unnecessary casts:**

You have to use the `T` variant for cases like this:

```
public <T extends Set> T firstOf(List<T> l) {
    return l.get(0);
}
```

With `?` this would become:

```
public Set firstOf2(List<? extends Set> l) {
    return l.get(0);
}
```

...which doesn't give the same amount of information to the caller of the `firstOf` method. The first version allows the caller to do this:

```
SubSet first = firstOf(listOfSubSet);
```

while with the second version, you are forced to use a cast to make it compile:

```
SubSet first = (SubSet)firstOf(listOfSubSet);
```

---

**To enforce matching argument types:**

```
public <T extends Set> boolean compareSets(List<T> a, List<T> b) {
    boolean same = true;
    for(T at : a) {
        for (T bt: b) {
             same &= at.equals(bt);
        }
    }
    return same;
}
```

There is no direct equivalent using `?` instead of `T` for this. Note that due to Java's single-dispatch, in the above version, the compiler will call `at`'s `equals(T)` method which may well differ from `at`'s `equals(Set)` or `equals(Object)` method.

Comment: Good examples. Another important point is that (while the name indicates it in this case) the version of the method that returns `Set` instead of `T extends Set` doesn't expose in its contract that it returns the same type the given `List` contains, which more generally would mean you couldn't rely on that being true.

Comment: Since `Set` as we know doesn't have `compare` method(s), it's difficult to understand what you mean by your 2nd example. If you are to add `compare` methods to `Set` to complete your example, what would their signatures be like? (Make sure it compiles before you present the code)

Comment: @irreputable: Good catch, I meant `equals` instead.

Comment: then if `a` and `b` are declared `List<? extends Set>`, the `equals(Set)` method will be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

The difference here is that in the second version, you have a type variable `T` that refers to the specific subtype of `Set` that the `List` contains. You need this in cases where you need to ensure that something else is the same type as the type contained in the list. A couple simple examples:

```
// want to ensure that the method returns the same type contained in the list
public <T extends Set> T something(List<T> list) {
  ...
}

// want to ensure both lists contain the exact same type
public <T extends Set> List<T> somethingElse(List<T> first, List<T> second) {
  ...
}
```

**Simple rule:** Use a type variable `T extends Foo` in your method signature if the same type is necessary in two places. Method parameters are each one place and the method return type is another place. Use the wildcard `? extends Foo` if you just need to ensure you're dealing with "something that is a `Foo`" in one place.

Aside: don't use the raw type `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

You use `List<? extends Set>` when you declare a varlable. For example:

```
List<? extends Number> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

`List<T extends Number>` can be used in class or methode declaration. This will allow you to write T instead of `<? extends Number>` later on in the function.

```
public <T extends Number> int addAll(List<T> list) {
    int result = 0;
    for (T t : list) {
        result += t.intValue();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You should pretty much never declare a variable of type `List<? extends Number>` when you create a `new ArrayList<Integer>()`. Just assign that to `List<Integer>`. Wildcards are for method arguments, to ensure you can use that `List<Integer>` anywhere you'd want to.

Comment: Also, your `addAll` method would work just fine with an argument of type `List<? extends Number>` (you don't actually make use of `T` at all), so this isn't a good example.

Comment: Ofcourse, you hardly even need the T in simple examples. At best it makes the code a little cleaner. T only becomes useful when you apply a double bound to T `T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>`. Using a bound wildcard is also more common in classes, List is declared as `public interface List<E> extends Collection<E>` and has variouse functions that take E as param or return type `E get(int index);`. I can't really think of a good 1 method example right now.

Answer (score 0):

We use wildcards to specify that the type element matches anything. The `?` stands for unknown type.

`List<? extends Set>` is an example of a *bounded wildcard*  and that states that the list can accept *any* subtype of a `Set` (e.g. `HashSet`)
`List<T extends Set>`, on the other hand is, allows `T` to be **bounded** to a type that extends `Set`.

I use wildcards when I need a collection of data irrespective pf it's exact type.

Comment: `add(? extends Set)` is semantically equivalent to `add(Set)`. Thus, why would you want to use `List<? extends Set>` instead of `List<Set>`?

Comment: Are you saying that the code in your example works? Because that won't compile (only `null` can be used for a parameter with a wildcard like `? extends Set`). You also can't create a `new ArrayList<? extends Set>()`.

Comment: @ColinD, yes, code never works...sorry, I removed my bad example.

Answer (score -1):

A wildcard type `G<? extends A>` is a super type of any `G<Ai>` where `Ai` is a subtype of `A`

In another word, `G<? extends A>` is the union type of `G<A0>, ..., G<An>`.

Comment: The question was what the difference between `T extends A` and `? extends A` is and when you'd use one over the other, not what `? extends A` is in the first place.

Comment: @Simon The real problem is that people don't know what wildcard is. They cope by some rules of thumb in specific use cases, without understanding why, like the rule of thumb in method signature, of which you offered 1 limited example.

Comment: I trust people to articulate themselves well enough. If that wasn't the case, I don't believe SO would be as useful as it is. That being said, people **do** know what a wildcard is. I had an excellent professor teaching type systems once admit that he saw little use in `<?>` and it triggered just about the discussion covered here.

Comment: Also, if I felt the OP really wanted to know what a wildcard is instead, I would have redirected him to a question actually stating that and give an answer there.